# How can I count two diffrent things in a query

Tags: php, mysql, count

I got this query:

```
$q = $mysql->query("
SELECT *, COUNT(`crimeDescription`) AS total_count 
FROM `crimes` 
GROUP BY `crimeDescription` 
ORDER BY COUNT(`crimeDescription`) DESC 
Limit 15") or die($mysql->error);
```

I also want to get the person who has had this crime issued most times against him (crimeIssuedTo)

Example:

```
1 | Grand Theft Auto | Most to: User_A | Total: 500
2 | Attempted Murder | Most to: User_C | Total: 453
3 | Assault          | Most to: User_D | Total: 451
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Please put your tables structure

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get top n records for each group of grouped results](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12113699/get-top-n-records-for-each-group-of-grouped-results)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about something like the following:

```
SELECT *, COUNT(*) AS total_count, 
(
  SELECT p.Username 
  FROM crimes AS sc
  INNER JOIN players AS p ON p.ID = sc.crimeIssuedTo
  WHERE sc.crimeDescription = sm.crimeDescription
  GROUP BY sc.crimeIssuedTo
  ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
  LIMIT 1
) AS PersonWithMostOffenses
FROM crimes AS sm
GROUP BY sm.crimeDescription
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC 
LIMIT 15
```

Comment: Hey thanks, it works, except it returns the ID and not the username on PersonsWithMostOffenses. What if I want to select Username from players where ID is PersonWithMostOffenses in the same query?

Comment: **@user3494083**, I updated my answer to join the `players` table in the sub query.  Let me know if that works for you.

Comment: Thanks a bunch! Also, how can I add another ( SELECT ) as ... in the same query, as I'd like to get PersonIssuedMost aswell

Comment: You would just follow the same pattern as in the above sub query.

Comment: Give the `PersonIssuedMost` query a try and if you have any problems with it, post another question.